# Ratio between two values with confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, paired-data, ratio

I have two integer values, each with confidence intervals, and I want to calculate the ratio between the two values.

My strategy would be to find all the pairs of integer values within the CIs and then calculate the ratio between them, so as to find the distribution of the ratio between the two values.

I can then calculate the average value, which I can interpret as the average value of the ratio between the two values with their CIs.

My questions are:

1. Is this strategy sounding or are there any issues?
2. Can I interpret the minimum and maximum ratio value I identified with the previous procedure as the Confidence Intervals of my ratio?
3. In the case the previous one is true, and considering that the starting confidence levels are 95%, is 95% also the confidence level of the ratio?

R code for a simple simulation:

```
# simulate data
# x = 250 ± 100
# y = 200 ± 50
x <- seq((250-100), (250+100), by=1)
y <- seq((200-50), (200+50), by=1)

# ratio between all combinations of values
comb <- expand.grid(x, y)
ratio <- comb$Var1/comb$Var2

# summary and histogram
summary(ratio)
hist(ratio)
```

[image: Histogram of ratio]

Comment: Analyzing ratios is often challenging. Ratios are "asymmetric" by nature:  decreases will fall between 0 and 1 and increases will fall as ratios greater than 1. A doubling is 2 while when you look at it the other way round (flipping numerator and denominator), the ratio is 0.5. So, these two values are not symmetrical around 1.0 while they should be comparable. Therefore, you might be interested at looking at the logarithm of ratios: increases and decreases will be on the same scale. You might find this useful: https://www.graphpad.com/support/faq/the-ratio-paired-t-test/

Comment: Are the quantities you have means of some data?  Are you willing to assume numerator and denominator are independent?

Comment: The quantities are sums. We can interpret one of the quantities as the number of subjects exposed to a content, and the other one, as the number of a particular action made by subjects in relation to that content. Therefore there is a certain relation between the quantities, since subjects can perform the action only when exposed to the content, however exposure do not directly impact the subjects' willingness to perform the action (indeed there is a very low correlation between these quantities).

Comment: Is this then any different from the number of successes out of $n$ trials (a binomial distribution), or am I missing something? Perhaps you could edit the question to be more about the problem and less about the proposed solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think that equidistant sampling of values from the confidence intervals produces representative samples, because the probability distribution inside the intervals is not taken into account.

There are, however, two possible sampling methods from measured (empirical) data that take the distribution into account:

1. The *Bootstrap*, which draws samples with replacement. Instead of merely counting quantiles of the bootstrap samples ("percentile bootstrap"), it is generally more advisable to use the $BC_a$ bootstrap ("bias corrected accelerated bootstrap").
2. The *Jackknife*, which cyclically omits one sample and then estimates the variance from the $n$ obtained values $\theta_{(i)}$ as
   $$\sigma_{JK}(\hat{\theta}) = \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\theta_{(i)}-\theta_{(.)})^2} \quad
    \mbox{ with }\quad \theta_{(.)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_{(i)}$$

The Bootstrap directly yields a non-parametric confidence interval, whilst the Jackknife yields a parametric confidence interval as $z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sigma_{JK}$.

Note that for the specific problem of a *ratio* of two variables, there is yet another method recently developed by Donner & Zhou named MOVER-R (published in 2012). There is even a readily available R implementation in the package pairwiseCI:

https://rdrr.io/cran/pairwiseCI/man/MOVERR.html